# Want to sort a csv file from 3rd column starting from end of line and not start

Tags: unix, sorting, csv

I want to sort a csv file using unix sort command and no of columns can very from line to line
But 3rd column from last remains the same how will i implement unix sort command to this file??

I have tried 
sort -t"," -k? filename.csv

but i couldnt figure out what to put in with k as it will be the no of column from start and not from last

sample data

```
"Hotel_Dom","4STRAVELCOMPANY@GMAIL.COM","4STRAVELCOMPANY@GMAIL.CO","NH57014106349",1280082600,"B2B","10037"
"Hotel_Dom","68MHOSPITALITY@GMAIL.COM","68MHOSPITALITY@GMAIL.COM","NH5520894246",1280023222,"B2B","1670"
"DF","00000000@11111.COM","FLTINT1000130394756","12800231456","B2C","6799.2"
"Rail","00000.POO@GMAIL.COM","NR251764697478",1280084511,"B2C","2025"
```

Now i want to sort it according to date using unix sort command So i have converted date to time since epoch but in my csv starting columns are varied in number so i want to apply sort to third line from last which is always date

Comment: Please, both rewrite your sentences and add a small sample of your input file, and the output you want; your question is confuse even to edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, '{print $(NF-2)FS$0}' filename.csv | sort -n |  sed 's/^[^,]*,//'
```

hope this works +

Comment: what is NF-2 doing?? i m getting this error fatal: attempt to access field -2

Comment: Since that first column is to be interpreted as a number (which the original question implies, though the OP didn't make this very clear), `sort -n` would be better, but +1, that's what I would have written.